# Get a list of meta values and search for posts Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, search, meta

how to link meta_values to make a search for posts  with the current meta?

The code above, show in a dropdown all the meta_value of city meta_key and cpt post type

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
//some code for title
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cpt',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'city',
    );
$dbResult = new WP_Query($args);

    echo '<ul class="menu dropdown-menu">';
            while ( $dbResult->have_posts() ) : $dbResult->the_post();
            $mykey_values = get_post_meta($id, 'city', false);
                foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) { 
                $by_link = esc_url(add_query_arg(array( 'b' => $value ))); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $by_link;?>">  <?php echo $value ?></a></li>  
            <?php   }
                endwhile;   ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

 <?php
    echo '</ul>'; ?>
</nav>
```

My problem is how to get a link of the values and search.

So to get a link, I tried

```
 $by_link = esc_url(add_query_arg(array( 'b' => $value ))); ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $by_link;?>">  <?php echo $value ?></a></li>
```

And to search I made another loop and tried to get b value:

```
<?php 
$meta_value = $_GET['b'] != '' ? $_GET['b'] :  '';
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'cpt',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,

    'meta_query'    =>  array(
                array(
                'key' => 'city',
                'value'  =>  $meta_value, 
                'compare' => 'LIKE', 
            ),
    ),
);
$dbResult2 = new WP_Query($args2);
 while ( $dbResult2->have_posts() ) : $dbResult2->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any help???

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct then you want to get a URL for each dropdown option. If so, you can do something like this-

```
echo '<ul class="menu dropdown-menu">';
    while ( $dbResult->have_posts() ) : $dbResult->the_post();

    $mykey_values = get_post_meta($id, 'city', false);

foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    $by_link = esc_url(add_query_arg(array( 'b' => $value ))); ?>
    <li data-url="<?php echo $by_link;?>"><?php echo $value ?></li>
<?php }

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
```

You can extend any element with 'data-' attributes. You can add any data attribute you wish- data-bla, data-blabla, data-whatever.

When you need that data, you can use jQuery to retrieve it-

```
(function() {
  $('.my-menu li').click(function() {
    var li_url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    // Do something here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Netanel, thanks for the answer, but, when I click, nothing happens and still does't search  for posts with the current meta

Comment: I tried with jquery, but there is something wrong. The page loads, but still doesn't make the right search. I guess is something with  var search_val... Here is the code $('.bairros-menu li').click(function() {
     var li_url = $(this).attr('data-url');
  var search_val=$(this).find('b').val();